# HTML in ASP.NET MVC page showing blank

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When launching the webpage, I'm taken to the address of

```
https://localhost:5001/ArtistAlbum/ArtistAlbumIndex
```

However, no data is displayed and I can't view the page source. It SHOULD display a table of artists and albums corresponding to my joined tables. There are no errors to debug, just a blank page after building and running. Any ideas?

Controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

using App.Models;
using ChinookContext;
using ChinookEntities;

namespace App.Controllers
{
    public class ArtistAlbumController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ArtistAlbumViewModel model = new ArtistAlbumViewModel();
            Chinook db = new Chinook();
            List<ArtistAlbum> artistAlbums = db.Artists.Join(db.Albums, 
                art => art.ArtistId, alb => alb.ArtistId, 
                (art, alb) => new ArtistAlbum() {
                    ArtistId = art.ArtistId,
                    Name = art.Name,
                    AlbumId = alb.AlbumId,
                    Title = alb.Title
                }
            ).ToList();
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

View model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using ChinookContext;
using ChinookEntities;

namespace App.Models
{
    public class ArtistAlbumViewModel
    {
        public List<ArtistAlbum> ArtistAlbums { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Entity class:

```
public class ArtistAlbum
{
    public Int32 ArtistId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 AlbumId { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
}
```

ArtistAlbumIndex view:

```
@using App.Models
@using ChinookEntities;
@model ArtistAlbumViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AlbumAritst Index</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>This is the ArtistAlbum index page!</h1>
    @* <p>@Model.paragraph</p> *@
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">Working</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (ArtistAlbum artistAlbum in @Model.ArtistAlbums)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@artistAlbum.Name</td>
                <td>@artistAlbum.Title</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Also for reference, the button code:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="ArtistAlbum" asp-action="ArtistAlbumIndex">ArtistAlbum Index</a>
</li>
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside your foreach, does Model.ArtistAlbums have any data?

Comment: @GHDevOps It seems to build past the breakpoint, so I assume so, yes